# pyodbc path in sql statement not working

Tags: python, copy, odbc, directory, pyodbc

I`m quite new to python and would like to copy a table from one mdb to another mdb using pyodbc. There seems to be a problem with the paths if a Foldername starts with a digit. I googled for an hour now and couldn't find a solution:

```
DBfile = r"W:\path\1020 Folder\MDB1.mdb"
conn = pyodbc.connect('DRIVER={Microsoft Access Driver (*.mdb)};DBQ='+DBfile1)
cursor = conn.cursor()

sql = """SELECT Table1.* INTO test FROM [W:\path\A 1020 Folder\MB2.mdb].Table1;""" 
sql1 = """SELECT Table1.* INTO test FROM [W:\path\1020 Folder\MB2.mdb].Table1;""" 

cursor.execute(sql) #WORKING
cursor.execute(sql1)  #NOT WORKING
conn.commit()
```

Thanks alot, Achim

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You must be very careful when you want to use backshlash `\` in strings. You can escape those using `\\`:

```
sql1 = """SELECT Table1.* INTO test FROM [W:\\path\\1020 Folder\\MB2.mdb].Table1;"""
```

You can also use raw string just like you did it with `DBfile`